# How can i resolve two distinct promises in a protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, promise, protractor

I am a beginner with Node.js.
I have a promise that downloads a file from a server, then parses it into a json object and returns it.
Another promise returns a webpage element().
The two promises have to be solved one after another: first the promise that returns json object,this work good, 
then the promise that gets the page element.
Using a key from the json object i have to test if the element contains the same text.

Code:

```
var menuItems = element(by.id('menu')).all(by.tagName('li'));

it('should contain', function (done) {
  jsonPromise.then(function () { // work
    console.log('Inside jsonPromise then');
    menuItems.then(function () { //------> not step into
      console.log('Inside menuItems then');
      expect(menuItems.get(0).getText()).toEqual(jsonData.home);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

With this code protractor returns: 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
Why is that? What am i doing wrong?

Note: both console command execute

Comment: which version of protractor are you using ? In [2.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) `element` does not return promise

Comment: I work with 2.0 version

Comment: Maybe an error happens?

Comment: The 'error' is : 1 test -->>>>>> 0 assertions <<<<<<------!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to **put the `jsonPromise` on the `protractor`'s [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/25aec6cac875b8b8e9a11a4cf5099c113359faa6/docs/control-flow.md#the-webdriver-control-flow)**:

```
browser.controlFlow().await(jsonPromise).then(function (data) {
    expect(menuItems.first().getText()).toEqual(data.home);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary as the testcase is asynchronous so Jasmine will wait until done is called

Comment: @Bulkan I am actually not sure either, but I remember putting some promise on the control flow helped me once. Hope this is helping here. If not, I'll remove the answer, not a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With protractor [2.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) WebElements `element` does not return a `Promise`

This should work

```
menuItems = element(by.id('menu')).all(by.tagName('li'));

describe('my tests', function(){
  it('should contain', function(done) {
    jsonPromise.then(function(jsonData) { 
      console.log('Inside jsonPromise then');
      expect(menuItems.get(0).getText()).toEqual(jsonData.home);
    })
    .then(done)
    .catch(done);
    // if using jasmine2 it will be .catch(done.fail)
  });
});
```

Comment: D:\java_workspace\project\public_html>protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
jsonPromise
.

Finished in 2.762 seconds
1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed

Comment: @KrauszLórántSzilveszter that does not look like an error. I don't believe it even ran your test case. I've updated the code in my answer to better handle errors.

Comment: @KrauszLórántSzilveszter that means that `jsonPromise` is not a promise. Can you update your question with how you create/get `jsonPromise` please ?

Comment: console.log('Is promise?', protractor.promise.isPromise(jsonPromise)); --> True

Comment: @KrauszLórántSzilveszter is your `it` in a `describe` block ?